# social login php and json

Tags: php, json

I've setup Janrain social login. The only thing left is to make it more of a personalized message when logging in using this. I have no experience with php at all. It's just a practice or demo page at https://www.ntademo.com/ where you can use social login through google+ or facebook.

Here's the very top of what's returned. What'd i'd like to do is return a friendly message when someone logs in using google+ or facebook. Thank you for any input on what I should do next.

Here's a php script called `rpx-token-url.php`

```
<?php

if ($token) {
    // Step 2: Use the token to make the auth_info API call.
    $post_data = array(
        'token' => $token,
        'apiKey' => $janrain_api_key,
        'format' => 'json'
    );
        'apiKey' => $janrain_api_key,
        'format' => 'json'
    );
    if ($social_login_pro) {
        $post_data['extended'] = 'true';  }
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://rpxnow.com/api/v2/auth_info';
    $result = curl_helper_post($curl, $url, $post_data);
    if ($result == false) {
        curl_helper_error($curl, $url, $post_data);
        die();
    }
    curl_close($curl); if ($auth_info['stat'] == 'ok') {
        echo "\n auth_info:";
        echo "\n"; var_dump($auth_info);
        if ($social_login_pro) {
            include('social_login_pro_examples.php');
        }
 } else {
        // Handle the auth_info error.
        output('An error occurred', $auth_info);
     output('result', $result);
    } } else {
    echo 'No authentication token.'; } $debug_out = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); ?> <head>
        <title>Janrain Token URL Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre><?php echo $debug_out; ?></pre>
    </body> </html>

auth_info:
array(4) {
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["profile"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["providerName"]=>
    string(7) "Google+"
    ["identifier"]=>
    string(53) "https://www.google.com/profiles/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(16) "My Name"
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["formatted"]=>
      string(16) "My Name"
      ["givenName"]=>
      string(4) "Mt"
      ["familyName"]=>
      string(11) "Name"
    }
    ["photo"]=>
    string(99) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=400"
    ["googleUserId"]=>
    string(21) "xxxxxxxxx"
    ["providerSpecifier"]=>
    string(10) "googleplus"
  }
  ["merged_poco"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(21) "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(16) "My Name"
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["formatted"]=>
      string(16) "My Name"
      ["givenName"]=>
      string(4) "My"
      ["familyName"]=>
      string(11) "Name"
    }
    ["languagesSpoken"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "en"
    }
    ["photos"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(99) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=400"
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "other"
      }
    }
  }
  ["accessCredentials"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["accessToken"]=>
    string(71) "ya29.Ci-vAwW_RMSVgS9r_VCFp1JySU5dz0UoqVCgwmej3-UTUQnW8NzkLP7qDgk9N4zzxA"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(21) "117971470422940045510"
    ["expires"]=>
    int(1481265328)
    ["refreshToken"]=>
    string(45) "1/JkuvkZkq060wASEY2DGUtko_AkCc_-xdyiFQFhF0PiQ"
    ["scopes"]=>
    string(7) "profile"
    ["clientId"]=>
    string(72) "407531817131-okq2ahfvs8ggkpmgvt6a31udmnahqemj.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "oauth2"
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, here is the top of what is returned in web browser after google+ auth as an example. Similar with FB.
 auth_info:
array(4) {
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["profile"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["providerName"]=>
    string(7) "Google+"
    ["identifier"]=>

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing:

```
<pre><?php echo $debug_out; ?></pre>
```

with:

```
<pre><?php 
    if(isset($auth_info) && $auth_info['stat'] == 'ok') 
        echo('Hello '.$auth_info['merged_poco']['displayName'].' thanks for logging in');
    else
        echo('Please log in'); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: That's almost there. For some reason it's either saying it can't be reached, hanging, or returning, "Congratulations, you\'re not logged in." So I'm about an inch away from completing this!

Comment: Also, do yo you know what i could add to personalitze it like hello Name thanks for logging in?

Comment: If the name appears in the $debug_out array you can, otherwise you will have to work out how to get the name another way.  This is really specific to the provider (eg: Google+) so I can't help without more info

Comment: Here's the top of page for if using Google+. I'm not really a developer so I'm kind of flailing on this. I enjoy this sort of thing but don't really know what I'm doing so thank you for the help. I appreciate it!

auth_info:
array(4) {
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["profile"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["providerName"]=>
    string(7) "Google+"
    ["identifier"]=>
    string(53) "https://www.google.com/profiles/xxxx"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(16) "My Name"

Comment: The dump you provided in your last comment seems incomplete so I had to guess a little and have updated my answer

Comment: I'll add to the bottom of original question so that it's legible.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the protocol but I replace my first name with 'My' and last name with 'Name' and then xxxx at end of URLs for profile.

Comment: I've taken a better look at the code.  It's formatted quite badly so it's difficult to follow.  I've reformatted it in my editor and it looks like there are parts missing so it's difficult for me to give you an accurate answer however I have edited my response so hopefully you get the name now.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I think the code was formatted okay in my source but then I messed with it getting it to look right in the markdown before I remembered about ctrl-K. Thank you. I'm going to try this out now.

Comment: That worked!!!!!!
Thank you. I did learn something and that is to learn to code I need to do actual little projects as I've been working on it through online courses and books for at least a year and don't seem to make that much progress. Even if some of it is getting help or copying and pasting some code, I feel this was more learning than a lot of little practice drills so far with JavaScript and Python not php though.